# Spring ControllerLoggingAspect doesnt intercept the method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following:

```
@Pointcut("execution(*com.shop.controller.OrderController.save(..))")
public void savingOrder() {
    log.info("Saving order details");
}

@Before("savingOrder() && args(..,request)")
public void logSavingOrder(JoinPoint joinPoint, HttpServletRequest request){
    log.info("Saving");
}
```

However, the log never gets displayed.

When I try the following:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.shop.controller.OrderController.saveOrder(..))")
public void savingOrder() {
    log.info("Saving order details");/**/
}

@Before("savingOrder()")
public void logSavingOrder(JoinPoint joinPoint){
    log.info("Saving order");
}
```

Everything works. However, I need to have access to the `HttpServletRequest`.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add it in the method signature of intercepting method, access it inside the intercepting method using one of the following methods:

If the bean is request scoped you can autowire the HttpServletRequest like:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class Foo {
    @Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;

    //
}
```

Otherwise you can get the current request as follows:

```
ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest req = sra.getRequest();
```

This uses thread-local under the covers.

If you are using Spring MVC that's all you need. If you are not using Spring MVC then you will need to register a RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter in your web.xml.